# Existence of Random variables when $X_n \to -\infty$ a.s. and $EX_n\to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, self-learning

Do there exist random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$  $$$$such that  $X_n \to -\infty$ a.s. and   $EX_n\to \infty$?

How would you prove or disprove this analytically?

Comment: The answer has been edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a simple example, fix the probability space $[0,1]$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure. Define random variables $X_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  by setting $$X_n(\omega) = \begin{cases} -n & \text{if } \omega > \frac{1}{n} \\
n^3 & \text{if } \omega \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$$

Then $X_n(\omega) \to - \infty$ for all $\omega > 0$ and hence $X_n \to - \infty$ a.e. However you can calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \frac{1}{n} n^3 - (1- \frac{1}{n})n = n^2 - n + 1 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Even though my question is silly. Could you explain to me why $X_n(\omega) \to - \infty$ ?

Comment: If $\omega > 0$ then there is an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $\frac{1}{n} < \omega$. This means that for each $\omega > 0$, for large enough $n$ $X_n(\omega) = - n$ which gives the convergence since $-n \to - \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Example: $P(X_n=-n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=n^3)=\frac{1}{n}$. So $E(X_n)=n^2-n+1\to \infty$.  However $X_n\to -\infty$ a.e.

Comment: They won't tend to $-\infty$ if family $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ would be independent

Comment: The answer has been edited!

Comment: @DominikKutek  What has independence got to do with it?

Comment: Borel Cantelli lemma, series $\mathbb P(X_n = n^3)$ diverges, so when events $\{ X_n = n^3 \}$ are independent, you won't have convergence to $-\infty$ since there will be almost surely infinitelly many indices $n_k$ such that $X_{n_k} = n_k^3$

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, you can easily modify the usual example of the typewriter sequence (see example 4 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/)) to get a sequence $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $X_n$ satisfies the conditions in your answer but doesn't converge pointwise at any point.

Comment: This is pretty easy to fix if you just use the other Borel-Cantelli  lemma. Take $P(X_n = -n) = 1- \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $P(X_n =n^4) = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: You're just looking for an example of a random variable so using Borel-Cantelli lemmas at all is overkill. Just define them so you know their joint behaviour to get around this problem (see my answer which uses this fix).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that when $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures and $p \in [0,1]$ then $\lambda = p\mu + (1-p)\nu$ is probability measure (that is: a convex combination of pr.measures is a pr. measure).

Let $\mu$ be probability measure (distribution) of positive part of Cauchy random variable, that is for any $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ we have $\mu(B) = \int_{B \cap \mathbb R_+} \frac{2\cdot dx}{\pi(1+x^2)}$

Let $\nu_n = \delta_{-n}$ be probability measure such that $\delta_{-n}(B) = 1 $ iff $-n \in B$ (that is one-point distribution).

Let $p_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \in [0,1]$, and finally let $\lambda_n = (1-p_n)\nu_n + p_n \mu$.

Define $X_n$ to have distribution $\lambda_n$, then we have: $$\mathbb E[X_n] = \int_{\mathbb R} x d\lambda_n(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{x}{n^2} d\mu(x) - n(1-\frac{1}{n^2}) = + \infty$$ since $\int_{\mathbb R} xd\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb R_+} \frac{2x}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx = +\infty $.

So obviously sequence of $+\infty$ tends to $+\infty$, so $\mathbb E[X_n] \to +\infty$.

Looking at $X_n$, take any $M \in \mathbb N$. We have: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n > -M) \le M + \sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n > -M) = M + \sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n \neq -n) = M + \sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ which is finite. This means that (Borel Cantelli) on the set of measure $1$ we have only finitelly many $X_n(\omega)$ being greater than $-M$, so $\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) \le -M$ for any $\omega$ in that set of measure $1$.

Since $M \in \mathbb N$ was arbitrary, we deduce that $\limsup X_n = -\infty$ almost surely, but obviously $\liminf X_n \le \limsup X_n$, so $\liminf X_n = \limsup X_n = -\infty$ almost surely, and that means that almost surely we have the limit which is $-\infty$